# where does ruby on rails app stores session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, redis

I am using the session to felicitate log in feature

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/simple-authentication-guide-with-ruby-on-rails-16a6255f0be8

Where is the session[:user_id] stored ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to the documentation:

> default and recommended session store - the CookieStore - which stores all session data in the cookie itself

Read more in the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)